# How can I make a Parameter mandatory depending on input Yes or No in Parameter above?

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script that will create new text files. Id like to ask the person if he wants to upload the files automatically to Azure storage Blob.
When they state Yes I'd like to ask 2 more Parameters before we continue with the script.

How can I make 2 Parameters mandatory depending on the input of Yes or No?

This is what I have now, but that doesn't work obviously. I just don't know how to get it to work with a Yes or No value in $Upload_Scripts_To_Azure.

```
   param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Remove_Old_Certificate,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Upload_Scripts_To_Azure,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string[]]$Servers,
        [parameter(Mandatory = (If ($Upload_Scripts_To_Azure -eq "Yes") 
   {$true 
    } else { $False })][string]$RSG,
    [parameter(Mandatory = (If ($Upload_Scripts_To_Azure -eq "Yes"){$true 
    } else { $False })][string]$AAN
    )
```

Can someone send me in the right direction? I've tried ParameterSets, but they seem to look at no input at all only.

Answer (score 0):

You "can" do something similar to this with dynamic parameters:

```
function test {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Remove_Old_Certificate,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Upload_Scripts_To_Azure,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$Servers
    )
    DynamicParam {
        If ($Upload_Scripts_To_Azure -eq "Yes")
        {
            $RSGAttr = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]::new()
            $RSGAttr.Mandatory = $true
            $AANAttr = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]::new()
            $AANAttr.Mandatory = $true
            $attrCol = new-object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attrCol.Add($RSGAttr)
            $RSGParam = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new('RSG', [string], $attrCol)
            $attrCol = new-object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attrCol.Add($AANAttr)
            $AANParam = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new('AAN', [string], $attrCol)
            $ParamsDict = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
            $ParamsDict.Add('RSG', $RSGParam)
            $ParamsDict.Add('AAN', $AANParam)
            return $ParamsDict
        }
    }
    Process
    {
        "RSG is $($PSBoundParameters.RSG)"
        "AAN is $($PSBoundParameters.AAN)"
    }
}
```

This will prompt you to enter a value for RSG and for AAN. The values are stored in `$PSBoundParameters` as a property, i.e. `$PSBoundParameters.RSG` and `$PSBoundParameters.AAN`.

**Output Running the Function:**

```
> test -Remove_Old_Certificate "SSLCert" -Upload_Scripts_To_Azure "Yes" -Servers "server1","server2"

cmdlet test at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
RSG: Group1
AAN: Something
RSG is Group1
AAN is Something

> test -Remove_Old_Certificate "SSLCert" -Upload_Scripts_To_Azure "No" -Servers "server1","server2"
RSG is
AAN is
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of it, you could make use of Parameter Sets.  It is basically a way to do pseudo "overloading" in PowerShell.

Here are some notable changes I might consider:

```bsh
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String[]]$ComputerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$RemoveCertificate,
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='Upload')]
    [String]$RSG,
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='NoUpload')]
    [String]$AAN
)
```

Any parameter without a ParameterSetName binding is available to all parameter sets, like ComputerName and RemoveOldCertificate.  Then, other parameters are only available if they belong to the same parameter set.  If you have 5 parameter sets, you have make a particular parameter available to some subset of those by adding it like so:

```bsh
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='SetTwo')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='SetFour')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='SetFive')]
    $Parameter
```

This removes the need for your upload parameter entirely, however you would benefit from making it a `[Switch]`, rather than a `[String]` if you retained it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-parameter-sets